# How to strip a filename of special characters?

Tags: terminal, bash, unix

I have a file with a name such as "Today's Date.txt"

What I am interested in is stripping away all special characters using the terminal  such as:

```
" - , ' ' [
```

The reason for this is because I plug these into a script later and it is too much of a headache accounting for and changing the names individually.

Spaces " " and Underscores "_" and the alphabet "A-Z, a-z" are ok and so is replacing the characters rather than erasing them.

At first I thought the terminal command "iconv" could help me by converting to a simpler encoding, but I tried out several of the encodings and it seems I might be mistaken.

I know regular expressions might help me but sadly I am not well versed in them. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2733144/regex-to-strip-special-characters) question that seems realated, but I dont know how to implement it or if it covers the same cases as mine.

The reason I posted this here is because this question might be unique to the character set OSX supports for filenames and the encoding it uses...although it's more likely I have no clue what I'm talking about.

Thank you for your help in advance.

Edit: The command

```
sed 's/[!@#\$%^&*()]//g'
```

Seems to work very well but I can't get it to work for my original usage case and others:

```
' ` "
```

Escaping them doesnt work either. I'm very new to bash scripting so please bear with me.

---

Edit 2: Posting this here or else I'd have to wait 6 hours.

In addition to Alan Shutko's Answer, I would like to add my own solution that I found.

```
awk '{gsub(/[[:punct:]]/,"")}1'
```

I'm kind of hesitant to post this since I cannot explain it well.

Awk, as it's man page says, is used for "pattern-directed scanning and processing language". The gsub function searches and replaces all occurrences of the regular expression you input. The gsub part would look like this:

```
gsub("a","b")
```

Where in my example, all occurences of a would be replaced by b. Like in the comment above [[:punct:]] sounds like it stands for all punctuation marks. However, I do not know what the 1 on the outside of the brackets stands for.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you have a specific set of characters that you want to keep, tr works very well.

For example

`tr -cd 'A-Za-z0-9_-'`

Will remove any characters not in the set of characters listed.  (The -d means delete, and the -c means the complement of the characters listed: in other words, any character not listed gets deleted.)

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Reading through the man page, the [:alnum:] flag is just as effective for displaying alphanumeric characters. Like So:

    tr -cd [:alphanum:]

We can conserve the spaces to by including [:blank:]

Answer (score 8):

This would only replace single quotes with underscores:

```
for f in *; do mv "$f" "${f//'/_}"; done
```

This would only keep alphanumeric ASCII characters, underscores, and periods:

```
for f in *; do mv "$f" "$(sed 's/[^0-9A-Za-z_.]/_/g' <<< "$f")"; done
```

Locales like `en_US.UTF-8` use the ASCII collation order on OS X, but `[[:alnum:]]` and `\w` also match characters like `ä` in them. If `LC_CTYPE` is `C`, multi-byte characters are replaced with multiple underscores.

Comment: Can this be done recursively?

Answer (score 3):

I recently had the same problem and had to strip the filenames of all files in a folder of special characters. I used this command, which is a combination of both answers posted here, but also keeps periods. Maybe it helps someone.

```
for file in *; do echo mv "$file" `echo $file | tr -cd 'A-Za-z0-9_.-'` ; done
```

removing the `echo` in front of `mv "$file"` executes the command.

Comment: Very useful to add a `for` loop to feed the file-names to `tr`. Also the inactivating `echo ` prefix is a great way to simulate and test critical commands first.

Answer (score 0):

I using this

```
for file in *; do echo mv \""$file"\" \"`echo $file | tr -cd 'A-Za-z0-9_-.[] '`\" ; done
```

removing the echo in front of mv "$file" executes the command.

Comment: How does this differ to [previously given answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/261183/371189) - please [edit] and explain the benefits or why you prefer this.