# All files in directory filename character removal script bug

Tags: macos, terminal, mac, finder, command-line

I'm trying to use [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/93322/how-to-strip-a-filename-of-special-characters) question to rename all the files in a directory and keep only [a-zA-Z0-9. ] (last character is a space).

The terminal entry I'm using is:

`for file in /Users/bob/Downloads/videos/*.mp4; do mv "$file" "$(sed 's/[^0-9A-Za-z. ]//g' <<< "$file")"; done`

### What's being done?

My *current* understanding, command by command, is:

[1] `for file in /Users/bob/Downloads/videos/*.mp4`

Creates a string variable called `file` which contains the text where `*` is, so if a file was called `my (awesome) kickass! video.mp4` the variable `file` would be a string containing `my (awesome) kickass! video.mp4`

[2] `do`

For each file that matches the pattern (a file with an mp4 extension) do the next commands

[3] `mv` "$file" "$(sed)"

Use the move file command to rename the matching file

[4] `"$(sed 's/[^0-9A-Za-z. ]//g'`

Use the stream editor command to do a regex find/replace.

Find every character which is not in the list and replace it with what is between the two forward slashes (nothing); ie, remove non-matching characters.

[5]  `<<< "$file")"; done`

I have no idea what the `<<<` operator(?) does, or what referencing back to the `file` variable does.

### Expected Result

A file named `my (awesome) kickass! video.mp4` is renamed to `my awesome kickass video.mp4` and stays in the same directory

### Actual Result

The file `my (awesome) kickass! video.mp4` is renamed to `UsersbobDownloadsvideosmy awesome kickass video.mp4` and is moved to the `Users` directory

Comment: An easy way to debug these kind of issues is to use `echo` to print the command with the processed/transformed data into Terminal (`...; do echo mv "$file" ...`) and look at the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$file` holds the absolute path, not the filename of your files.

In your example, `$file` would be `/Users/bob/Downloads/videos/my (awesome) kickass! video.mp4`.
Since `/` is not part of the 'legal' character set, it will be removed by `sed` leading to the move command:

`mv "/Users/bob/Downloads/videos/my (awesome) kickass! video.mp4" "UsersbobDownloadsvideosmy awesome kickass video.mp4"`

When you are running the command in the terminal, your current directory is probably the user directory, meaning that the file at the absoulte path gets moved into the current directory and renamed to the name you see.

**Possible fixes**

- simple workaround: add '/' to the set of 'legal' characters, so that sed wont replace it
- other, maybe cleaner, option: change the regex in sed to only remove the given characters at the end of the path. That should be possible by using groups and having the first regex group match the directory path and the last group the filename without unwanted characters (which is the last bunch of characters without '/')
- yet another option: before your loop, `cd` into the directory with the files and then iterate over `*.mp4` instead of the absolute path. This should give filenames in `$file` making the rest of the script work as expected.

Comment: `$ basename /Users/bob/Downloads/videos/my_video.mp4` is `my_video.mp4` so OP can just use `basename` on `"$file"` in the `sed` invocation

Comment: @Bakuriu without an appropriate `cd`, this would move all renamed files into the current directory.